# Get the URL of a web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am working on a asp.net web forms application and in it I create a link and send it in an email for user's to reset their password.

The only issue is, when the link is created for a user outside the network the link displays the server's name and port number instead of the website name they used to access it.

For example, if I access `https://testsite.com` and then I generate the email, the link comes up as
`https://testserver:1111`

I want the link in the email to be: `https://testsite.com/reset?key=value`

Here is my code to create the link

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" 
         + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority 
         + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') 
         + "/PasswordReset.aspx;
```

How can I get the code to display the website name and not the server's name?

Could this be an issue with the web server (I am using IIS)?

Comment: Your domain is defined in DNS, which your app cannot access easily.  If you're sending an email from a direct user action with a postback or something, you might be able to get the url from the referrer in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Using an answer from another solution on SO, I used this code:

```
int lastSlash = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].LastIndexOf('/');
string uri = (lastSlash > -1) ?
           HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].Substring(0, lastSlash) :
           HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];

// Return the link with leading slashes
return uri + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/')
           + "/PasswordReset.aspx?key=value"
```

I needed to use the Server variable `HTTP_REFERER` to get the correct url.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the appSettings or just HttpContext.Current.Request["HTTP_HOST"]

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DOMAIN" value="www.mysite.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

And the just

```
string domain = HttpContext.Current.Request["HTTP_HOST"];
string myUrl = "";    

 if(HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection) 
   myUrl = string.Format("https://{0}/passwordreset.aspx?key={1}",domain,yourvalue);  
 else 
   myUrl = string.Format("http://{0}/passwordreset.aspx?key={1}",domain,yourvalue);  

// do something with your myUrl.
```

Comment: The `Request["HTTP_HOST"]` method did not work. It still returned the server name and port number. The only issue with the `<appSettings>` solution is that if any users is on the same network as the server it won't display the page to them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` instead of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority`.

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority` return the DNS name and Port number for the server. That's why you are getting DNS (testserver) and port number (1111)  `https://testserver:1111` link in your email.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I am still getting the server name and port number. Could this be because the external site name is set up on the web server?